# How to re-use the same FetchRequest, rather than the same request in several views?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui

I use the same fetch request in multiple top level views under ContentView. I mean the same entity / predicate etc.

Previously I tried doing the request once in ContentView and passing it as an array through several layers of views. However, this stopped changes, deletes etc, being propagated across other views.

I just wondered if there is another approach which would work ?

I'm thinking that some kind of singleton approach might work, but I'm worried about the performance implications, however this might outweigh having to run the request several times.

Also, I wondered about passing a request results rather than array?
However having to pass this around seems ugly.

Comment: May be create a static var in one of your struct one class so you can access it with MyClassOrStruct.sharedRequest

Comment: Look into architectures, VIPER, MVC, etc. which is best is opinion based and out of scope and also impossible to answers since we don’t have much info

Comment: @PtitXav thanks, but would this get updated?

Comment: @loremipsum basically the request would be something selected and added to my other entity. Although there is a list and edit screens for it.

Comment: by fetch request, you mean a network call made with URLSession?

Comment: @Honey no a core data call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Environment` to pass your models to children without having to passing an array through several layers of views. You start by creating your own `EnvirnomentKey`

```
public struct ModelEnvironmentKey: EnvironmentKey {
    public static var defaultValue: [Model] = []
}

public extension EnvironmentValues {
    var models: [Model] {
        get { self[ModelEnvironmentKey] }
        set { self[ModelEnvironmentKey] = newValue }
    }
}

public extension View {
    func setModels(_ models: [Model]) -> some View {
        environment(\.models,  models)
    }
}
```

I like using `ViewModifiers` to setup my environment, following the Single-Responsibility Principle:

```
struct ModelsLoaderViewModifier: ViewModifier {
    @FetchRequest(entity: Model(), sortDescriptors: [])
    var models: FetchedResults<Model>
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .setModels(Array(models))
    }
}

extension View {
    func loadModels() -> some View {
        modifier(ModelsLoaderViewModifier)
    }
}
```

I then would add this modifier pretty high on the view hierarchy.

```
@main
struct BudgetApp: App {
    @ObservedObject var persistenceManager = PersistenceManager(usage: .main)
    let startup = Startup()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .loadModels()
        }
    }
}
```

Now `ContentView` can read from the environment:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.models) var models
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(models) { model in
                Text(model.name)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, will this show updates made in different views while on another child view?

Comment: Yes, as changes to the context are made, the results of the fetch request will be updated, `ModelsLoaderViewModifier` will be updated and it will update the environment value with the models.